# How are Bounce Management email domains generated?

Tags: email, bounce-management

With Bounce Management enabled, when I send an email to a lead from a Salesforce org, the sender's `smtp.mailfrom` property appears as follows.

> martyc=example.com__11isvlfxp7f8lvm9.y6yenshnuv0yenlp@kbkhv95j1kx61wqh.9sw88.6a-2gprrua4.na50.bnc.salesforce.com

Can anyone explain to me or help me understand how the **kbkhv95j1kx61wqh.9sw88.6a-2gprrua4.na50.bnc.salesforce.com** domain was generated by Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

It's got some kind of encrypted data; when a bounce mail is sent back to the origin (say, because the email was not found, or has a full inbox), this email address is decrypted in order to update the appropriate record(s). Presumably, the precise content of this address isn't something you can find out unless you sign an NDA with Salesforce and someone internally gives you that information.